# Registration with Zend Framework 1.12 Confirmation email mechanism

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, email-verification, email-confirmation

I have used email verification for user login and authentication. I have written a code so that the status becomes `status=1` when he clicks on the link sent to his email. And then he is redirected to login page. He needs to login with the same details given in registration. I have written a validation such that when the email address and password match then the user is authenticated and he is logged in. But I need to add one more condition that the validation must also check whether the status is 1, and user must be allowed to login only when `status=1`. For this I need to add a variable in the login action and check for `where status=1`. How do I do this?
In the below code I am getting validation for only `email` and `password`. How to get `status=1` condition satisfied?

This is  my **loginAction**

```
     public function loginAction()
{
    if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())
    {
        $this->_helper->redirector('register','user','default');
    }
    $authAdapter = $this->getAuthAdapter();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $post=$this->_request->getPost();           
    $email = $post['user_email'];
    $password = $post['password'];
    $authAdapter->setIdentity($email)
                ->setCredential($password);
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
    if($result->isvalid()){
        $identity = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject();
        $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
        $authStorage->write($identity);
    $this->_helper->redirector('register','user','default');
        echo 'valid';
    } else {
        $this->view->errorMessage = "User name or password is incorrect";
    }
```

}

This is my **statusAction**

```
     public function statusAction()
{
    $url = explode('&',urldecode($this->_getParam('k')));
    $data['email'] = $url[0];
    $data['status'] = 1;
    $data['access_key'] =  $url[1];
    $mapper = new Application_Model_UserMapper();
    $status = $mapper->update($data); 
    $this->_helper->redirector('index','projects','default');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give your AuthAdapter an where clause for your status field:

```
$select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
$select->where('status' = 1);
```

So it looks like this:

```
$authAdapter = $this->getAuthAdapter();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $post = $this->_request->getPost();           
    $email = $post['user_email'];
    $password = $post['password'];

    $authAdapter->setIdentity($email)
                ->setCredential($password);

    // and status is equal 1            
    $select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
    $select->where('status' = 1);

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

if($result->isvalid()){
    $identity = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject();
    $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
    $authStorage->write($identity); 
    $this->_helper->redirector('register','user','default');
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    $this->view->errorMessage = "User name or password is incorrect";
}
```

Not tested, but should work ;)

Comment: could you provide some more infos pleasE? ;)